# no guarda los datos en la base de dato

Tags: html, laravel

Tengo un problema con mi código, al querer ingresar a mi ruta para ingresar datos me aparece el siguiente error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'patente'
>   cannot be null (SQL: insert into `cars` (`patente`, `marca`, `modelo`,
>   `color`, `fecha_in ▶

¿alguien sabe qué puedo hacer?

```
public function ingresar(Request $request){


        $patente=$request['patente'];

        $marca=$request['marca'];

        $modelo=$request['modelo'];

        $color=$request['color'];

        $fecha_ingreso=$request['fecha_ingreso'];

        $car=new Car();

        $car->patente=$patente;

        $car->marca=$marca;

        $car->modelo=$modelo;

        $car->color=$color;

        $car->fecha_ingreso=$fecha_ingreso;

        $car->save();

        return redirect()->back();

    }

web.php

Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/ingresar',[

    'uses'=>'CarController@ingresar',

    'as'=>'cars.ingresar'

]);
```

Pequeña muestra de mi formulario

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6"></div>

                <form action="{{route('cars.ingresar')}}"  method="post">

                   @csrf

                   <div class="row form-group">

                        <div class="col-md-12">

                            <label for="true">Patente:</label>

                            <input type="text" name="patente" size="6" maxlength="6"  class="form-control"  required>

                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: Desconozco de php, pero el mensaje es muy claro, la variable "patente" no esta recibiendo ningun valor. Trata de revisar tu formulario y revisa por que el valor de "patente" esta vacio.

Comment: Si hacés un `dd($request['patente'])` en tu método `ingresar()` qué devuelve? Y `dd($request->patente)`?

Comment: En dd($request['patente']) y en el otro me devuelve un Null

Comment: `Request` hace referencia a que clase? Declaraste al principio del controlador `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`? El resto de las variables si traen algo?